# How do you reference an entry immediately after it's been added to a dataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, arraycollection, drag-and-drop

I have a drag-and-drop event form in a flex project.  I need to run a validator right after the item is dragged into the dataGrid.  In it, I fire off a function through dragDrop="verifyEventUsers()".  In the validator, I compare the contents of the two arrayCollections, but it appears to be running the checks prior to completion of the drop.  For instance, if I drag an element into the dataGrid and trace eventUsers.length inside the validator, I get zero.  When I drag the second element, it traces as one even though two lines now appear.

How can I set up a validation script that runs after the drag-drop action has finished?

Comment: As an additional note, running eventUsers.refresh() within the validator doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution just a few minutes after asking the question.  In this situation, I have one source grid and one destination grid, so it's easy.  In the dragDrop function, I used event.preventDefault();  I can then look at the selected row of the source grid, check the necessary conditions and drop the element in the target only if those conditions are met.